# Is there an application of the angle between two functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, geometry, angle, applications

In inner product spaces on $\mathbb{R}$, an angle between two vectors can be defined.

In particular, in function spaces, an angle between two functions can be defined.

Can the value of angle be used for something other than determining parallelism or orthogonality?

Comment: Look up orthogonal polynomials. They have several uses. Books have been written about them, so you should probably ask a more focused question.

Comment: The concept of an angle is principially just a remapping of the normed inner product, which always can be interpreted as a measure for the quality of independence and orientation. The absolute value indicates dependence if it is $1$, orthogonality at $0$ and various states of independence in between. The sign tells us if the vectors tend to be orientated the same way or in opposite ways.

Comment: Unlike the situation of Cartesian spaces where there is a fairly standard inner product, function spaces do not have a standard inner product. Further, domains matter; asking for the inner product of $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, for example, is asking for trouble. The point is, in asking about "the angle between two functions" it's advisable to be Very Explicit about what inner product you're using on Exactly Which function space.