# What is the interpretation of the 'angle' between functions? Since $\langle f(x), g(x) \rangle= |f||g| \cos \alpha(?)$can be viewed as a inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The inner product in a 'regular' vector space can be seen as:

$$ \langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle = \sum v_i w_i = |v| |w| \cos \alpha $$

So the 'sum' expression and the 'angle' expression are equal, but different ways to calculate the dot product.

The angle $\alpha$ is easily visualized as the angle between the vectors $v$ and $w$.

Now for function vector spaces we have the inner product:

$$ \langle f(x), g(x) \rangle =\int f(x)^*g(x)dx = |f||g| \cos \alpha ....(?)$$

The following connection is kind of intuitive, by going from a discrete sum to a continuous sum/integral:

$$ \sum v_i w_i \rightarrow \int f(x)^*g(x)dx $$

However is there any validity to:

$$ \langle f(x), g(x) \rangle = |f||g| \cos \alpha ....(?)$$

I think here $|f|$ is calculated with $\int |f|^2 dx $, however what does the $\alpha$ in this case express? Is there a way to intuitively understand the 'angle' between functions?

Comment: $|f|$ is the *square root* of $\int |f|^2$.

Comment: I would rather say that $\alpha (f,g)$ is defined by $$\alpha (f,g)=\arccos\left(\frac{\left<f,g\right>}{\|f\|\|g\|}\right).$$

Comment: I suppose a better question would be -- why should we care? Do we really care about the "angle" between functions, except when they're orthogonal? That orthogonality is convenient when it comes to expressions w.r.t. certain bases, but even if we could say that $e^{x^2}$ is $47^\circ$ off of $\sin(x)$ (whatever that would mean), would there be a point?

Comment: Related MSE questions: [Applications of angles in infinite-dimensional inner product spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4627617/13130) AND [Is there an application of the angle between two functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4524105/13130) See also (including their list of references) [*Geometry of Inner Product Spaces*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230701100329/https://sites.lafayette.edu/thompsmc/files/2015/08/Section_6_21.pdf) **(continued)**

Comment: AND [*Angles between infinite dimensional subspaces with applications to the Rayleigh–Ritz and alternating projectors methods*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123610002302) by Knyazev/Jujunashvili/Argentati (2010) AND (in the more general context of normed linear spaces) [*Angles and a classification of normed spaces*](https://www.google.com/search?q=10.15352%2Fafa%2F1399899841) by Volker W‎. ‎Thürey (2013; see also [this 2021 paper by Thürey](https://stm.bookpi.org/NUPSR-V9/article/view/1938)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's important to check that this angle can be properly defined. Supposing we want to write:

$$ \theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\langle f, g \rangle}{\|f\|\|g\|}\right),$$

we want to be sure that the quantity inside the $\cos^{-1}$ is in $[-1,1]$, so we can find such an $\theta$. This is guaranteed by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which says that $|\langle f,g \rangle| \leq \|f\|\|g\|$, so that $-1 \leq \frac{\langle f, g \rangle}{\|f\|\|g\|} \leq 1$. Thus, we *can* say that there is an angle $\theta$ between $f$ and $g$.

As for interpretation, I think it's useful to think of projections. This figure below shows that, in Euclidean space, if I want to project $a$ onto $b$, the length of the projection is $\|a\| \cos \theta$. If $\theta  = 0$, so that the $a$ an $b$ are parallel, the projection has length $\|a\|$. If $\theta = \pi/2$, so that $a$ and $b$ are perpendicular, the projection has length $0$.

The same intuition works for functions. $\cos \theta$ measures the extent to which $f$ shrinks when projected on to $g$, or vice versa. And if you're wondering how to define this projection, the defining property is that $f - \operatorname{proj}_{g}(f)$ should be perpendicular to $g$, or equivalently, that $\operatorname{proj}_{g}(f)$ is the closest point to $f$ on the line passing through $g$, which in the case of functions is simply $\{cg \mid c \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

So perhaps I will summarize things as follows: $\cos \theta$ tells us how much $f$ shrinks when we project it on to its closest constant multiple of $g$, or vice versa.

[image]